# "Internal testing" in Google Play shows app without "open" button! Why?

Tags: android, google-play

I've completed all the internal testing requirements as this image shows "available to internal testers". But the review is not done yet.

[image]

[image]

But when I install it on my phone, I can't open it! (my phone is POCO X3 Pro) The "open" button doesn't show!

[image: test]

How can I open it? Is it "available to internal testers" after the review finishes?

P.S. It is worth mentioning that the Android app works perfectly within the simulator and direct USB testing on the phone.

**EDIT**:

After enabling "Internal App Sharing", the app name displayed changes but no "Open" button is shown.

[image: Internal App Sharing Enabled]

**EDIT2**:

This is how the app page looks like when uninstalled.
[image: uninstalled image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the issue was not in Google Play store nor console but in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file for the project.

There were two [`<data>` elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element) in my `AndroidManifest.xml` project file located in two different `<activity>` and `<intent-filter>` tags. They both had the same `android:scheme` name.

```
...
<data android:scheme="XYZ" />
...
```

Deleting one fixed the "open" button issue.

You would think that something in the `adb logcat` log would complain about the malformed `AndroidManifest.xml` file but I read nothing to that effect. Is there something that checks the sanity of `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
...
11-15 09:11:28.673  1917  2035 I PackageDexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dexoptNeeded=1) on: /data/app/~~XcPti8zaRFpP7-RtoNMfGw==/com.XYZ.android-iWLcGjyquYwgtiJrVA5xqg==/base.apk pkg=com.XYZ.android isa=arm64 dexoptFlags=boot_complete,profile_guided,public,enable_hidden_api_checks targetFilter=speed-profile oatDir=/data/app/~~XcPti8zaRFpP7-RtoNMfGw==/com.XYZ.android-iWLcGjyquYwgtiJrVA5xqg==/oat classLoaderContext=PCL[]{PCL[/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar]}
11-15 09:11:28.674  1517  2368 V installd: DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/~~XcPti8zaRFpP7-RtoNMfGw==/com.XYZ.android-iWLcGjyquYwgtiJrVA5xqg==/base.apk' ---
11-15 09:11:28.686 20959 20973 W System  : A resource failed to call release.
11-15 09:11:28.686 20959 20973 W System  : A resource failed to call release.
11-15 09:11:28.688 27841 27841 I dex2oat32: dex2oat of ppid 1517, cpu affinity is set to 0,1,4,5,2,3,6,7, success.
11-15 09:11:28.688 27841 27841 I dex2oat32: /apex/com.android.art/bin/dex2oat32 --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=9 --call-from-installd=1 --updatable-bcp-packages-file=/system/etc/updatable-bcp-packages.txt --resolve-startup-const-strings=true --max-image-block-size=524288 --compiler-filter=speed-profile -j6 --classpath-dir=/data/app/~~XcPti8zaRFpP7-RtoNMfGw==/com.XYZ.android-iWLcGjyquYwgtiJrVA5xqg== --class-loader-context=PCL[]{PCL[/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar]} --generate-mini-debug-info --compact-dex-level=none --compilation-reason=install
11-15 09:11:28.690 27841 27841 I dex2oat32: setting boot class path to /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/miuisdk@boot.jar:/system/framework/miuisystemsdk@boot.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/com.nxp.nfc.nq.pn553.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar
11-15 09:11:28.794   996  1121 I SDM     : StrategyImpl::SetIdleTimeoutMs: Idle timeout: active = 70, inactive = 520
11-15 09:11:29.043  2793  2793 D BatteryController: onReceive: Intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } action = android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-15 09:11:29.043  2793  2793 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-15 09:11:29.043  3147  3147 D UCDetectService: action is android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-15 09:11:29.043  3147  3147 D UCDetectService: onEventReceive6 : USB plug = 2
11-15 09:11:29.043  3020  3020 D QtiCarrierConfigHelper: WARNING, no carrier configs on phone Id: 0
11-15 09:11:29.043  3020  3020 D VideoCall_LowBattery: disconnectVideoCalls on low battery
11-15 09:11:29.043  3020  3020 D VideoCall_LowBattery: disconnectVideoCalls
11-15 09:11:29.044  6386  6386 I BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
11-15 09:11:29.044  6627  6859 D PowerCheckerService: onBatteryChanged, mBatteryLevel = 16, status = 2, level = 16, plug = 2, scale = 100
11-15 09:11:29.045  3089  3089 D DeviceStatisticsService: chargerType=2 batteryLevel=16 totalBatteryCapacity=5791700
11-15 09:11:29.139 27841 27841 I dex2oat32: dex2oat took 451.644ms (1.559s cpu) (threads: 6) arena alloc=5304B (5304B) java alloc=7371KB (7548856B) native alloc=9415KB (9641456B) free=836KB (856592B)
11-15 09:11:29.146  1517  2368 V installd: DexInv: --- END '/data/app/~~XcPti8zaRFpP7-RtoNMfGw==/com.XYZ.android-iWLcGjyquYwgtiJrVA5xqg==/base.apk' (success) ---
11-15 09:11:29.146  1917  2035 W BpBinder: PerfMonitor binderTransact :  time=472ms interface=android.os.IInstalld code=18
11-15 09:11:29.147  1917  2035 I InstallationStatistic: com.XYZ.android|null|4260|1085|31|2397|179|474
11-15 09:11:29.150  1517  2368 E installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl444984305.tmp: No such file or directory
11-15 09:11:29.150  1517  2368 E installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl444984305.tmp: No such file or directory
11-15 09:11:29.151 27789 27789 W BpBinder: PerfMonitor binderTransact :  time=3179ms interface=android.content.pm.IPackageManager code=1598246212
11-15 09:11:29.151 27789 27792 I cmd     : oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
...
```

Comment: For anyone else encountering this - in my case the culprit was `<intent-filter>` where I merged two separate intents into one. Crazy thing is that everything worked in testing, with not even a warning in Android Studio or when publishing to Google Play. It just could not be opened on device when installed from Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

you should add your account as a **tester** and you should enable internal testing from Google Play store.

from Play store go to **settings** > **General** > enable **Internal app sharing**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Check the edit on the question to see that I'm an internal tester but no "open" button is shown.

Comment: If you unistall the app what does appear to you? Also I noticed that the app is only available in 2 countries, maybe this is related to your problem.

Comment: I've added all 176 countries. The uninstalled image is edited in the question.